# Getting values from dropdown list jquery in the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

Is it possible to get the values from two different dropdown list in the same class whenever either of them is clicked in jQuery without having to write two change functions. For instance:

```
    <div class="selectList">
            <select id="prodVersionList" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select id="prodAudienceList" style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it is. What is your use case and what are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to get both data selected and run a rest call for instance $getJson("api/v2/facets" + 'where facet=' + dataselected1 + 'where facet=' +dataselected2)

Comment: @charlietfl I want to combine both in my API call to return a result, so for instance I want to get both data selected and run a rest call for instance $getJson("api/v2/facets" + '?where facet=' + dataselected1 + 'where facet=' +dataselected2). dataselected1 and dataselected2 being the options from the dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!

Multiple ways to do it however you can just watch the selects (you can use the id's if you'd like) however I am just watching all selects.

```js
$('select').change((e) => {
   var selected =  $("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectList">
            <select id="prodVersionList" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select id="prodAudienceList" style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

The above will return an array to you with the two values. Basically I just find all selected options and create a simple array out of them.

EDIT: Sorry! I misread initially and gave a half right answer. Here is an accurate one.

Edit V2: Because someone was pointing out possible confusion here is something more directed.

```js
$('.selectList select').change((e) => {
   var selected =  $(".selectList > select > option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectList">
            <select id="prodVersionList" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select id="prodAudienceList" style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="altSelect">
    <select id="prodVersionList" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select id="prodAudienceList" style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or another one:

```js
$('#prodVersionList,#prodAudienceList').change((e) => {
   var selected =  $(".selectList > select > option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectList">
            <select id="prodVersionList" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select id="prodAudienceList" style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="altSelect">
    <select style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 25px;  margin-right: 20px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">All Products</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pen</option>
                <option selected="selected">Pencil</option>
            </select>
            <select style="float: right; width: 150px; height: 25px;">
                <option selected="selected">All Versions</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.0</option>
                <option selected="selected">1.1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is development, there are a million ways to accomplish a task. I was not intending to spoonfeed each possibility but merely give a way to accomplish this.

Comment: question: is the selector $('option:selected') going to find every option element on the page or only the option for the context of the current select element? If so, that causes a problem if wanting to only get values for select elements inside of container elements using a specific class name.

Comment: Sure which I mentioned, he could simply use a class or ID. For the purposes of my demonstration I simply made a catch all for selects. He could just as easily have watched each select ID. As noted, a million ways to do it, I simply showed one.

Comment: @daddygames I have added 2 other ways to limit things even further. At the end of the day, this is software development, I'm sure people can figure out how to specify things even further. The root of the question was to get two values, i've answered that in multiple ways.

Comment: I see more to your answer now than I saw before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the select elements inside the div with class "selectList" and identify each selected option in the lists found. Compile into an array (or whatever) for later use.

```
var values = new Array();
$('.selectList select').on('change', function(){
    values = new Array();
    $('.selectList select').find(":selected").each(function(){
        values.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

[EDIT] updated so that the array is reset and populated when a new selection is made

Comment: This is going to keep pushing all the values into the array continuosly when i add on change to it. ["Pen","1.0", "1.1","Pen", "Pencil", "1.1"]

Comment: I'll prefer at each instance, get the two values, then when i click on any one again, get the two values at that time

Comment: @teestunna you may have misunderstood my example. The array was just there to show how you could capture the selected text. I've updated the example to ensure that the array resets and populates each time a new selection is made. How you decide to capture the information is really up to you.